# JavaScript: How to iterate through a table and remove the second cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say that I have a very simple table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>TextFirst</td>
      <td>TextSecond</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I traverse the table and remove "TextSecond".  The table could be any number of rows or cells.

Comment: you only need to take out the second or ALL the TextSecond?

Comment: Do you want to do this for every row? Or just the first? What are the conditions that must be met for removal to occur?

Comment: I want to do it for every row and there may be more rows.

Comment: $("table td:nth-child(2)").remove()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("table td:nth-child(2)").remove()
```

Comment: You might want to take a read of [the mark-down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for code-formatting. :)

Comment: kek i wrote it as fast as i could sorry :P ill fix that up right now

Comment: No worries; it seemed odd that you didn't know how to format code with a rep >2000... :)

Answer (score 3):

In your posted example you have, at least, two options I can think of:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Or:

```
$('tr td:eq(1)').remove(); // zero-based index, thanks @ZDYN for the catch
```

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
var removeThis = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
removeThis.parentNode.removeChild(removeThis);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6DWLC/).

Comment: I believe `:eq()` index is 0-based.

Comment: Oh... **darn**, yeah: you're right! Sigh...I knew that, too. +1 for good eyes, and a thank you. **edited into answer** :)

Comment: in your plain js, would i not have to make a loop somehow?  it looks like it is only doing one

Comment: @William, it is, yeah; but I don't know what logic you're following to remove the second `td` elements. You say that "[the] table could be any number of rows or cells" but don't define how many, or whether it's always the second `td` of the row, or just the `td` that contains the string "TextSecond" and without that information, I can't really offer a more thorough alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //var table = document.getElementById("?");
    for (i=0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        if (table.rows[i].cells.length > 1)
            table.rows[i].cells[1].removeNode(true);
    }
```

or if you want to delete cells based on some condition. just because

```
    //var table = document.getElementById("?");
    for (i=0; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = table.rows[i].cells.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == 'TextSecond')
                table.rows[i].cells[j].removeNode(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child`... :
`$('table :nth-child(2)').remove();`
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pV6cD/)